# How to extract Subject/Person from sentence using Regex in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I want to match and extract subject and person from the following format of strings:
((When|Where) is)? (my|the)? (next)? (subject)? (meeting|event)? (with (person))?

Possible sentences:

When is my meeting with David Sharma(Person=David Sharma)?
Where is the lunch(Subject=Lunch) meeting?
When is the Friday lunch(Subject=Friday Lunch)?
Where is my next dinner(Subject) event with John(Person)?

Here is my result after various attempts but some query or the other doesn't match properly:

```
 if (preg_match("/(?:(?:when|where)\s+is\s+)?(?:(?:my|the|your)\s+)?(?:next\s+)?((\S+\s+|\S+\s+\S+)+)?(?:(?:event|meeting)\s+)?(?:with\s+(.*))?/", $query, $matches)) {  
  print_r($matches[1]); //subject  
  print_r($matches[2]); //person  
}
```

Comment: shouldn't *meeting|event* be subject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Regex: `^(?:when|where) is(?: (?:my|the|your))?(?: next)?(?: (?:((?!event|meeting)[\w ]+?)))?(?: (?:event|meeting))?(?: with ([\w ]+))?\?$`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EaDe9T/3)

Comment: my|the|your is optional. I forked your regex and tried to make it optional. But it didn't match "When is meeting with Dave?" forked regex: https://regex101.com/r/hu38tn/2

Comment: I've updated the regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/hu38tn/3).if it works for you, I'll update the post.